# Screen flickering intermittently

Tags: display

My desktop intermittently flickers. I run it as a media server. I initially suspected it may be the graphics card, so I have since replaced this; but, alas, the screen has started flickering again. It does this completely at random – I reboot the computer and all is fine again for some time, and then it starts again! Could this be the start of a hard disk failure? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how often if flickers, you can leave your PC at the BIOS set up screen and don't boot your operating system and see if it ever flickers. Or you could boot it with a free "Live" version of Linux from a CD, DVD, or USB drive and see if the problem goes away running a different operating system.

If it never flickers, except when booted into your OS, it's likely a driver problem or possibly malware. If it does still flicker, even when not running your OS, it's very likely the monitor or cable.

If you suspect malware, and you're running Windows and don't already have it, the free version of Malwarebytes is well regarded and one of the better "lightweight" malware scanners (just don't agree to the free trial for the paid version).

It's not your hard drive and very unlikely to be your power supply. If the power supply is faulty enough to glitch the video the entire PC would be locking up.

Comment: I shall try that malware programme and see what comes up its far to intermittent for me to leave it at bios to do that its and so the catalyst centre constantly monitors drivers the tv is brand new and I have tried other hdmi leads

Answer (score 0):

This is most commonly due to bad or out of date drivers for your graphics card. For a quick, and no-cost fix check this first before assuming it is a hardware problem.

Hardware wise this is often the sign of a bad monitor. Have you tried a different monitor? Different cables? Different power strip?

Hard disk failure seems unlikely for the symptoms. Internal to the computer, the most likely cause would be either bad motherboard or bad PSU.

Comment: It's and so catalyst control centre is constantly monitoring drivers it's a 50" Sony that is hooked up to that's only 6 months old I have tried different hdmi but only have three at my disposal as they are buried in the wall