# Pc flickering randomly. (Displaying either random colours or static)

Tags: desktop

[Similar unsolved issue](https://superuser.com/questions/886561/screen-flickering-intermittently)
I have elitedesk 8300 i7-3770. After using it for sometime, it can start flickering until it shutdown.it can also flicker while installing Kali OS, while resetting windows, while using Windows recovery environment.
If I force it to sleep while flickering, pc functions normally upon waking up.
I have tried using remote desktop protocol ( RDP or chrome remote desktop) and pc just shutdown after sometime without flickering.
It functions normally after rebooting.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yt2G6.jpg)

Comment: do you have a question?

Comment: Yes. What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try another video cable or monitor.

Comment: The pc can automatically shutdown when using RDP/chrome remote desktop without monitor connected to pc. So I think the pc has more problem than the monitor/video cable.